# All TLS requests giving Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user

Tags: ssl, curl, nss

When I try an https request to google.com, I just recently started seeing

```
[root@ip-172-31-47-76 ~]# curl -I -v https://google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://google.com/
*   Trying 216.58.193.78...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.com (216.58.193.78) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.google.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*       start date: Feb 20 14:17:23 2018 GMT
*       expire date: May 15 14:08:00 2018 GMT
*       common name: *.google.com
*       issuer: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US
* NSS error -8172 (SEC_ERROR_UNTRUSTED_ISSUER)
* Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

This is affecting my ability to update the system as yum update requests fail as well.  I've tried reimporting my certificates using the instructions on this page: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549003.  I've also tried manually adding Google cert using the instructions here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html.  Neither worked.

I'm not sure if it's related but I tried troubleshooting further with the certutil utility but that can't be run

```
[root@ip-172-31-47-76 ~]# certutil
certutil: /usr/local/firefox/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.30' not found (required by certutil)
```

Not quite sure what happened here but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Based on the Admin comment, this question has been moved here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429091/all-tls-requests-giving-peers-certificate-issuer-has-been-marked-as-not-trusted.